# Syntax highlight a vimrc file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

So, this might be a heretical question, but I'm looking for an Emacs mode that handles syntax highlighting of .vimrc files. This particular question has proved pretty hard to Google for the obvious reasons, but it seems extremely likely to me that *someone* would have written such a mode in the 20+ years of open warfare between the two editors. Any ideas?

Comment: Dude, this is the best idea ever for trolling #emacs. :)

Comment: +1 and better luck on superuser. The logic being that administrators are far more likely to be emacs users that need to mess around with .vimrc files than a programmer is.

Comment: +1 For the audacity of the question.  If there were, I'd expect a Google for 'vimrc.el' or 'vimrc.elc' to turn up something, but absolutely nothing is raised, much to my lack of surprise.  It would be like a hammer and sickle embossed with the stars and stripes. ;-)

Comment: This question is the first hit on Google when looking for 'emacs .vimrc mode' :).  Besides, I don't expect a mode to be available for .vimrc.  I did find modes for conf files and xdefaults on my Emacs but none for .vimrc.  The closest I did find wasvi-mode and vpier.  So if you are planning on writing one, you are probably the first to do so :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Googling does turn up [wenbinye's vimrc-mode](http://code.google.com/p/dot-emacs/source/browse/trunk/wenbinye/config/20-func.el), a very lightweight generic mode. Here's what I have in my `.emacs`:

```
(define-generic-mode 'vimrc-generic-mode
    '()
    '()
    '(("^[\t ]*:?\\(!\\|ab\\|map\\|unmap\\)[^\r\n\"]*\"[^\r\n\"]*\\(\"[^\r\n\"]*\"[^\r\n\"]*\\)*$"
       (0 font-lock-warning-face))
      ("\\(^\\|[\t ]\\)\\(\".*\\)$"
      (2 font-lock-comment-face))
      ("\"\\([^\n\r\"\\]\\|\\.\\)*\""
       (0 font-lock-string-face)))
    '("/vimrc\\'" "\\.vim\\(rc\\)?\\'")
    '((lambda ()
        (modify-syntax-entry ?\" ".")))
    "Generic mode for Vim configuration files.")
```

Comment: That mode correctly highlights comments, but comment filling with M-q does not work properly.  To fix comment filling, you have to tell the mode what comments look like by replacing the first `'()` with `'("\"")`.

Comment: @enoksrd It does work if you haven't turned on Filladapt mode (which I have). But I'm not convinced this is right, as `"` doubles as comment and string syntax.

Comment: what is the concern? That you would use `M-q` in a code block and have it wrap your strings as comments?  Why would you use `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) in your code?

Comment: It seems the linked reference has changed theirs simply to `(define-generic-mode vimrc-mode
  '("\"")
  '("set" "syntax")
  nil
  '("\\.vim\\'")
  nil)`,
further, that there is now a `vimrc-mode` available on Melpa. It looks nice, but for some mistreating of quotes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great package for this: https://github.com/mcandre/vimrc-mode

Install by `M-x package-install vimrc-mode`.

It highlights `vimrc` files with amazing syntax highlighting automatically when they are opened, or you can invoke it manually via `(vimrc-mode)`.